# output hive query result as csv enclosed in quotes

Tags: csv, hive, export-to-csv

I have to export data from a hive table in a csv file in which fields are enclosed in double quotes.

So far I am able to generate a csv without quotes using the following query

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/vikas/output'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT QUERY
```

The output generated looks like

```
1,Vikas Saxena,Banking,JL5
```

However, I need the output as

```
"1","Vikas Saxena","Banking","JL5"
```

I tried changing the query to

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/vikas/output'
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)
SELECT QUERY
```

But it displays error

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'ROW' 'FORMAT' 'SERDE'
```

Comment: So why don't you just create an EXTERNAL TABLE mapped to that directory, INSERT in it, then DROP the table?

Comment: use hive concat. i.e. concat("\"",col,"\"")

Answer (score 0):

Create an external table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE new_table(field1 type1, ...)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"separatorChar" = ",",
"quoteChar" = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/vikas/output';
```

Then select into that table:

```
insert into new_table select * from original_table;
```

Your CSV is then on disk at /user/vikas/output

Comment: This writes the csv without a header. Is there a way to also get the header to write too?

Comment: Need advise on the above, need data with headers.