# How to output hive table as a standard csv file with quotes?

Tags: sql, hive

use below code to simulate my problem on your hive.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS tst;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tst.t_data (
   id       INT
  ,name     STRING
  ,value    BIGINT
  ,dt       STRING
)
;

SET hive.exec.compress.output=false;
INSERT INTO TABLE tst.t_data
SELECT id, name, value, dt
FROM (
SELECT 1 AS id, "ABC" AS name, 300000 AS value, "2021-09-01" AS dt UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, "DEF" AS name, 400000 AS value, "2021-09-01" AS dt UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS id, "GHI" AS name, 500000 AS value, "2021-09-01" AS dt UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS id, "JKL" AS name, 600000 AS value, "2021-09-02" AS dt UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS id, "MNO" AS name, 700000 AS value, "2021-09-02" AS dt UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS id, "PQR" AS name, 800000 AS value, "2021-09-03" AS dt
) a;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tst.t_serde (
   id       INT
  ,name     STRING
  ,value    BIGINT
)
PARTITIONED BY (
   dt       STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar" = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
;


SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=false;

INSERT INTO TABLE tst.t_serde PARTITION (dt)
SELECT id, name, value, dt
FROM tst.t_data
;
```

-- If i do dfs cat, i am getting proper csv values with double quotes and commas.

```
hdfs dfs -cat 'hdfs://ns1/user/hive/warehouse/tst.db/t_serde/dt=*/*' > t_serde_1.csv;

cat t_serde_1.csv

/*
"1","ABC","300000"
"2","DEF","400000"
"3","GHI","500000"
"4","JKL","600000"
"5","MNO","700000"
"6","PQR","800000"
*/
```

-- Problem, If i do normal select * statement from same table, i am getting tab separated values and without quotes

```
hive -e "SET hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict; SET hive.cli.print.header=false; SELECT * FROM tst.t_serde;" > t_serde_2.csv &

cat t_serde_2.csv
/*
1  ABC   300000   2021-09-01
2  DEF   400000   2021-09-01
3  GHI   500000   2021-09-01
4  JKL   600000   2021-09-02
5  MNO   700000   2021-09-02
6  PQR   800000   2021-09-03
*/
```

Is there any way to achieve the output like t_serde_1.csv using select statement in hive-1.2.1 ?

Comment: @drum Thanks for reply, but no it doesn't exactly answers my question.

Comment: This has answer. You can create a new external table (with "") and dump data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609581/output-hive-query-result-as-csv-enclosed-in-quotes